# Are C# static methods synchronized and locked?

Tags: c#, methods, static, synchronization, locking

I have a static class that gets me a client..

```
public static ClientFactory {

    private static Lazy<IClient> _MyClient;

    public static IClient GetClient(ICache cache) {

        if (_MyClient == null) {
            _MyClient = new Lazy<IClient>(() => CreateClient(cache));
        }

        return _MyClient.Value;
    }

    private static IClient CreateClient(ICache cache) {
        // code that takes 1-2 seconds to complete
        return new Client(cache);
    }
}
```

Is there any chance that I can have 2 or more clients created by writing code like this? Where the second client would overwrite the first one?

How should I update my code in a way, such that the constructor is called only once per application?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are static methods thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090650/are-static-methods-thread-safe) and [How to make static method thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976618/how-to-make-static-method-thread-safe) and [What does MethodImplOptions.Synchronized do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223656/what-does-methodimploptions-synchronized-do) and [C# : What if a static method is called from multiple threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037637/c-sharp-what-if-a-static-method-is-called-from-multiple-threads)

Comment: `Is there any chance that I can have 2 or more clients created by writing code like this?` Yes.

Comment: Also, be aware that the default `Lazy` caches exceptions, which is very unlikely to be the behaviour you want. So if `CreateClient` has _any_ possibility of throwing an exception you should consider using https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092 .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code can result in multiple `Client` objects created.  Use a [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) to create the `Lazy<IClient>` instance:

```
public static ClientFactory
{
    ...

    static ClientFactory()
    {
        _myClient = new Lazy<IClient>(() => CreateClient());
    }

    public IClient GetClient() => _myClient.Value;
}
```

Example execution from your code:

1. thread A evaluates `_myClient == null` as true, enters block
2. thread B evaluates `_myClient == null` as true, enters block
3. thread A creates `Lazy<IClient>` object and sets `_myClient` field
4. thread A exits `if` block
5. before thread B sets `_myClient` field with a new `Lazy<IClient>` object, thread A accesses `_myCilent.Value` property, resulting in the creation of your `Client` object
6. thread B sets the `_myClient` field to its new `Lazy<IClient>` object
7. thread B accesses the `_myClient.Value` property, creating a second `Client` object
8. all subsequent calls to `GetClient` will return this second instance of `Client`

Comment: Why use a static constructor? Why not just assign on the same line as the declaration? `private static Lazy<object> _MyClient = new Lazy<object>(() => CreateClient());`

Comment: so, in this case, if many calls are made to do _MyClient.Value am I guaranteed to have created only 1 instance?

Comment: yes as the static constructor is guaranteed to execute only once per application domain and will execute before any other method in the class can be externally called

Comment: @mjwills yes, inline initialization would produce the same results in this case

Comment: So, what should I do my GetClient call needs to have some objects passed in? How do I do that with a single static constructor?

Comment: I guess I will use a lock() in my constructor code then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a chance, consider this example, based on your input, a run of this simple program may result in initialization of one or two clients (run multiple times to see):

```
void Main()
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke(
        () => ClientFactory.GetClient(1),
        () => ClientFactory.GetClient(2));  
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public static class ClientFactory {

    private static Lazy<IClient> _MyClient;

    public static IClient GetClient(int init) {
        Console.WriteLine(_MyClient == null);
        if (_MyClient == null) {
            Console.WriteLine(init);
            _MyClient = new Lazy<IClient>(() => CreateClient());
        }       
        return _MyClient.Value;
    }

    private static IClient CreateClient() {
        // code that takes 1-2 seconds to complete
        return new Client();
    }
}

public interface IClient {

}

public class Client : IClient {
    public Client() {
        Console.WriteLine("Client constucrtor");
    }
}
```

Two threads may be within the `if (_MyClient == null)` clause in the same time, creating multiple objects, only one assigned.